Receiving Run-Time error 3436 Failure creating file
Receiving Run-Time error 3436 when running the script below:
Debug highlights "DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
td.Name, out_file, True, Replace(td.Name, "dbo_", "")"
    Private Sub getTBL_Click()
Dim td As DAO.TableDef, db As DAO.Database
Dim out_file As String

out_file = CurrentProject.Path & "C:\Users\Desktop\excel_out.xls"

Set db = CurrentDb()
   For Each td In db.TableDefs
     If Left(td.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
     '// do nothing -- skip
   Else
     DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
     td.Name, out_file, True, Replace(td.Name, "dbo_", "")
   End If
   Next
End Sub


The range parameter is for imports only. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet

Please check the value of out_file. The combining of two complete paths looks wrong.

@Shrotter you referring to changing out_file = CurrentProject.Path & "C:\Users\joshua\Desktop\excel_out.xlsx"
to something like
out_file = "C:\Users\joshua\Desktop\excel_out.xlsx"

This version includes 2 significant changes:

Discarded the sixth argument (Range) from DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, per Warcupine
Supplied a valid location for the output file, per Shrotter

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim out_file As String

out_file = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "exel_out.xls"
Set db = CurrentDb()
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*") Then
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            tdf.Name, out_file, True
    End If
Next


i keep getting run time error 3125, Import Error. Debub is highlighting the two DoCmd lines

What does Debug.Print out_file show you when you get that error?

not sure if i'm placing in the correct spot but Debug.Print out_file generates a syntax error and highlights this:
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
tdf.Name, Debug.Print out_file, True

No, not that.  When you attempt to run your code and encounter that 3125 error, press the "Debug" button near the bottom of the error message window.  Then go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there) and paste in Debug.Print out_file and press Enter.

Afterward you can go to the VB main menu and choose Run->Reset to exit "break" mode.

The point of this effort is to inspect the string contained in the out_file variable.  I'm trying real hard to figure out why code which works fine for me is triggering an error for you.  The file destination seems like it could be the culprit.
